# Alternate row colour for dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, colors

Trying to build on from this: [Python: Color pandas dataframe based on MultiIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59769161/python-color-pandas-dataframe-based-on-multiindex)

I've extended the code:

```
import pandas as pd

i = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(0, 'zero'), (0, 'one'), (1, 'zero'), (1, 'one'), (1, 'two'), (1, 'three'), (1, 'four'), (2, 'zero'), (2, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (2, 'three'), (2, 'four')], names=['level_0', 'level_1'])
df = pd.DataFrame(range(0, len(i)), index=i, columns=['foo']) 

colors = {0: (0.6, 0.8, 0.8, 1), 1: (1, 0.9, 0.4, 1), 2: (0.6, 0.8, 0.8, 1)}
#convert rgba to integers
c1 = {k: (int(r * 255),int(g * 255),int(b * 255), a) for k, (r,g,b,a) in colors.items()}
c2 = {k: (int(r * 255),int(g * 255),int(b * 255), 0.25) for k, (r,g,b,a) in colors.items()}

#get values of first level of MulitIndex
idx = df.index.get_level_values(0)
#counter per first level for pair and unpair coloring
zipped = zip(df.groupby(idx).cumcount(), enumerate(idx))

css = [{'selector': f'.row{i}', 'props': [('background-color', f'rgba{c1[j]}')]} 
       if v % 2 == 0 
       else {'selector': f'.row{i}', 'props': [('background-color', f'rgba{c2[j]}')]} 
       for v,(i, j) in zipped]

df1.style.set_table_styles(css)
```

And got this:

[image]

It seems tedious to do this manually. So how do I go about generalising it so that it covers all rows, and the pattern applies even if I apply it to other such 2-level multi-index dataframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it with [cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) from Python standard library's [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) module:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Setup

i = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [
        (0, "zero"),
        (0, "one"),
        (1, "zero"),
        (1, "one"),
        (1, "two"),
        (1, "three"),
        (1, "four"),
        (2, "zero"),
        (2, "one"),
        (2, "two"),
        (2, "three"),
        (2, "four"),
        (3, "one"),
    ],
    names=["level_0", "level_1"],
)
df = pd.DataFrame(range(0, len(i)), index=i, columns=["foo"])
```

```py
# Define two pairs of colors (dark and light green/yellow)

from itertools import cycle

colors = [(0.6, 0.8, 0.8), (1, 0.9, 0.4)]  # green, yellow
color_cycle = cycle(
    [
        {
            k: (int(c[0] * 255), int(c[1] * 255), int(c[2] * 255), a)
            for k, a in enumerate([1, 0.25])
        }
        for c in colors
    ]
)
```

```py
# Define color for each row

bg_colors = []

for i in df.index.get_level_values(0).unique():
    color = next(color_cycle)
    row_color = cycle(
        [
            {
                "props": [("background-color", f"rgba{color[0]}")],
            },
            {
                "props": [("background-color", f"rgba{color[1]}")],
            },
        ]
    )
    for _ in range(df.loc[(i,), :].shape[0]):
        bg_colors.append(next(row_color))
```

```py
# Style dataframe

css = [{"selector": f".row{i}"} | color for i, color in enumerate(bg_colors)]
df.style.set_table_styles(css)
```

Output from last cell in Jupyter notebook:

[image]